# write a log files into device using cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic/cordova to building mobile application. For debugging an application, i want to write a log file using file system and store it in to device(i.e, some where in the SDcard). Is there any way to achieve this functionality using phonegap.

Can anybody suggest some useful links?

Answer (score 1):

Put this line log.bat file, this will open the console and logging every thing happend on the device.

```
adb logcat CordovaActivity:V CordovaWebView:V CordovaWebViewClient:V IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient:V CordovaLog:V *:S
```

**Update:** To write on file:
A [good example](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) to follow, but you need handle error callbacks, to get the error

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
    console.log("got main dir",dir);
    dir.getFile("log.txt", {create:true}, function(file) {
        console.log("got the file", file);
        logOb = file;
        writeLog("App started");            
    });
});


function writeLog(str) {
    if(!logOb) return;
    var log = str + " [" + (new Date()) + "]\n";
    console.log("going to log "+log);
    logOb.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

        var blob = new Blob([log], {type:'text/plain'});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
        console.log("ok, in theory i worked");
    }, fail);
}

    document.querySelector("#actionOne").addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
    //Ok, normal stuff for actionOne here
    //
    //Now log it
    writeLog("actionOne fired");
}, false);



  document.querySelector("#actionTwo").addEventListener("touchend",              function(e) {
        //Ok, normal stuff for actionTwo here
        //
        //Now log it
        writeLog("actionTwo fired");
    }, false);
```

and finally:

```
function justForTesting() {
logOb.file(function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.log(this.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
}, fail);

}
```

Here's the [source](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) for the explanaition.

I hope that help, good luck

Comment: thanks..but how we can  execute and where do we need to place it?

Answer (score 1):

You  can do it by the adding next plugin in your app:

https://github.com/pbakondy/filelogger

Comment: I tried log-to-file but When I tried with cordova install I'm getting compilation issues and when I tried with npm install I'm getting class not found in 

window.logToFile.setLogfilePath(logPath, function () {
console.log("Logger Logpath set Successfully")
}, function (err) {
console.log("Logger Logpath not set", err)
});

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in cordova way, writing a file called log.txt and put your log in there.

Please follow this [tutorial](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) for how to do this in cordova.

for ionic: 
You can put these codes inside your controller.

Comment: I have tried using the above code but not working(i.e, not able creating the file)

Comment: That sort of a progress, only problem is now , you need to add permission to manifest file : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I already have an entry in manifest file. but it is showing inside 'cdvfile', where we can find this folder?

Comment: Follow this thread: https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader/issues/39